# Cplex If-then binary constraint not updating

Tags: java, if-statement, cplex

I am new at cplex and I am trying to optimize a function of x by creating a binary variable in constraint such that:

if x[i] > 0 then y[i] = 1 or if x[i] = 0 then y[i] = 0

and then constraint is the summation of y < some number. The constraint are getting created as I want but the y's are not getting updated while solving the optimization.

I created an expression by adding each y which is later used in constraint along with upper bound and lower bound.

```
IloNumVar[] y = cplex.numVarArray(size, 0, 1);
IloLinearNumExpr expr = cplex.linearNumExpr();

for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
      cplex.ifThen(cplex.ge(x[k], 1), cplex.eq(y[k], 1));
      cplex.ifThen(cplex.eq(x[k], 0), cplex.eq(y[k], 0));
      expr.addTerm(1, y[k]);
      }
cplex.addLe(expr,ub);
cplex.addGe(expr,lb);
```

The .lp gives me the proper constraints but while solving it is not updating the y values and that's why the results are not making sense. I was wondering if there is a way to do. I tried doing cplex.addTerm(cplex(ifThen...)) but it doesn't take constraints as input. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You condition is malformed. You have

```
  cplex.ifThen(cplex.ge(x[k], 0), cplex.eq(y[k], 1));
  cplex.ifThen(cplex.eq(x[k], 0), cplex.eq(y[k], 0));
```

The first case is `x[k] >= 0` and the second case is `x[k] == 0`. So the case in which `x[k] == 0` is ambiguous. If `x[k]` is integer, than use `>= 1` in the first case, otherwise use an appropriate epsilon.

Also, you are not adding those constraints to the model (so I am not clear how you can see them in the .lp). You need to call `cplex.ifThen()` only constructs the constraints. You still have to add them:

```
  cplex.add(cplex.ifThen(cplex.ge(x[k], 0), cplex.eq(y[k], 1)));
  cplex.add(cplex.ifThen(cplex.eq(x[k], 0), cplex.eq(y[k], 0)));
```

**Edit after comments:**
In case you want to have a more complex expression in the "then" part of the if-then constraint, you can just build that more complex expression as usual:

```
IloLinearNumExpr sum = cplex.linearNumExpr();
for (int k : ...) sum.addTerm(y[k], 1.0);
cplex.add(cplex.ifThen(cplex.ge(x[k], 0), cplex.eq(sum, 1)));
```

This adds a constraint "if x[k] >= 0 then the sum of y[k] must be 1".

Comment: Hi Daniel,
My bad on the first part. I have corrected that. About the second part, the code that you recommended will only add y[i]'s to the constraint but I want the summation on y[i] to be added in the constraint. Thanks.

Comment: And the reason I can see it in the .lp is because I have created an 
IloLinearNumExpr expr and adding that.

Comment: I have added my answer to have the sum of y[k] in the "then" part of the constraint.